# How can I optionally pass rustc flags depending on a Cargo feature?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The program I'm writing runs much faster when the `-C target-cpu=native`  flag is passed to `rustc`. I want to give users a simple, platform-independent way to enable this when compiling, so I added a Cargo feature `cpu_native = []` in Cargo.toml and created this Cargo config in my project:

```
[target.'cfg(cpu_native)']
rustflags = ["-C", "target-cpu=native"]
```

However, this has no effect on my program, and passing `--features cpu_native` to Cargo does not even trigger a recompile. Changing to the following Cargo config *does* force re-compilation with faster instructions:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-cpu=native"]
```

However, this will compile with `target-cpu=native` with the default Cargo features, which was not what I wanted. From the Cargo book, what I want seems to be possible, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is supported (yet?). I enhanced Cargo to print out what config flags are checked against when resolving:

```
[
    Name("debug_assertions"),
    Name("proc_macro"),
    KeyPair("target_arch", "x86_64"),
    KeyPair("target_endian", "little"),
    KeyPair("target_env", ""),
    KeyPair("target_family", "unix"),
    KeyPair("target_os", "macos"),
    KeyPair("target_pointer_width", "64"),
    Name("unix"),
]
```

> `[target.'cfg(cpu_native)']`

This is the incorrect syntax for a Cargo feature; it would normally be `cfg(feature = "cpu_native")`.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure that's the exact same issue, but has the same keywords ("target" and "feature").