# Can I set Cargo project's default features depending on the platform?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to make the list of `default` [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) platform dependent in your `Cargo.toml`? I'd like to use features to select platform-dependent dependencies.

I'd imagine something like this:

```toml
[features]
# on Unix
default = ["feature-a"]
# not on Unix
default = ["feature-b"]

feature-a = ["dep-a"]
feature-b = ["dep-b"]

[dependencies]
dep-a = { version = "*", optional = true }
dep-b = { version = "*", optional = true }
```

I've tried:

- Using `[target.'cfg(unix)'.features]` does not work, it is ignored:

  ```toml
  [target.'cfg(unix)'.features]
  default = ["feature-a"]
  # -- snip --
  ```
- Using a `build.rs` script to enable features based on `cfg` conditions only partially works. Dependency resolution is done before running `build.rs`, so this won't import optional dependencies for features enabled in it. This example won't import `dep-a`:

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      #[cfg(unix)]
      println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=feature=\"feature-a\"");
      // -- snip --
  }
  ```

Can this be achieved within Rust itself, without external scripts?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to enable crate features per-platform in Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56908077/155423)

Answer (score 1):

`winit`'s workaround for this is to just have the features do nothing on the platforms where they're not supported. e.g. the `x11` and `wayland` features do nothing on the platforms where they're not supported.

In order for this to be a bit cleaner, they use the `cfg_aliases` crate to make new cfg flags: https://docs.rs/cfg_aliases/latest/cfg_aliases/

How winit uses it for x11/wayland: https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/blob/fbea75d31f4025825e9bf88b99d7c92e4eb79273/build.rs#L47

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different `features` under each `cfg`. There is no support of `cfg` for root section `features`. So you can reach your goal but in a different way.

You can have different dependencies with different set of features.

For example:

```
[target.'cfg( target_os = "android" )'.dependencies]
some_dep = { version = "0.3.0", features = [ "feature1" ] }

[target.'cfg( target_os = "ios" )'.dependencies]
some_dep = { version = "0.3.0", features = [ "feature2" ] }
```

[Official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies).

Comment: This does not achieve the same as having a different set of `default` features on different platforms.

Comment: Is not? You can specify different `features` under each `cfg`. There is no support of `cfg` for section `features`. So you can reach your goal but in a different way.

Comment: Section [Platform specific dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html) of The Cargo Book explains how to use different features of dependencies depending on a platform. In 2022 there is no way to make default depending on a platform. But you can reach the same goal with help of explained in the section technique.

Comment: This does not achieve the same goal. With this approach the end user has no way of managing used features using `--no-default-features` and `--features`. That's why I explicitly stated to make the `default` set platform dependent, rather than selecting dependency features based on the current platform.